# delete a part of field value in database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a column in my database table with name 'sent_to' that has values like :

{"ids":["6694","3449","5003"]}

Now i want to delete one of the id, say 3449 from this field,i.e. update 'sent_to' to: {"ids":["6694","5003"]}.

I am using codeigniter(mvc framework) and I tried the following in the model :

```
   $sql="   UPDATE web_query
        SET
        'sent_to'=REPLACE('sent_to','\"{$id}\"','')
        WHERE conversation_id='{$c_id}'";
   $this->db->query($sql);
```

But this is not working. Any idea, how to do this? Also I want to delete the whole row if the id I want to remove is the only id present in the 'sent_to' field.

Comment: You should use CI Active Records http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: if youre storing data stuff json encoded, you have to select the data from the database, decode it, update the data, encode it, and then update the database